# Ionic - Cordova Card.io plugin keepApplicationTheme doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, card.io

Per Cordova Card.io documentation -

keepApplicationTheme    Boolean

The theme for the card.io Activity's will be set to the theme of the application.

However, regardless if i set it to true or false the theme color doesn't adopt my app's theme.  I am using iOS and testing it on iPhone.  Everything else works fine.  Can some please advise?

Comment: The parameter `keepApplicationTheme` is an android-only option.  Maybe we need to clarify that in the docs.

Comment: Then what do I do with the iOS?  It looks out of place.